# ClassNotFoundException with imported. aar

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I am using two internal libraries in a company project. I imported the .aar files, then added them as dependences in Projedt Structure-> "+" button under declared dependencies. That generated the following lines in my app-level gradle file:

```
dependencies {

implementation project(path: ':libprinter-debug')
implementation project(path: ':libprinter-release')

}
```

I"m still getting  this error

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/github/rholder/retry/RetryerBuilder;`

Caused by:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.rholder.retry.RetryerBuilder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.appname-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.appname-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

None of the other instances of this question yielded a solution. I've cleaned and rebuilt several times. What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AAR files don't come with transitive dependencies. If the libraries depend on other libraries, you need to add them separately.

Searching with the class name, looks like you'd need at least

```
implementation "com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:2.0.0"
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for teaching me about transitive dependencies. I still have an error but it's not that one, so thanks!

Comment: And I solved that error by adding the whole all of guave/Google Core libraries to my project. (https://github.com/google/guava) 

Yay!